# How to make a python program measuring nanoseconds between keystroke dynamics?

Tags: python, time, keyboard-events, keystroke, pynput

I'm trying make a python program initiating a nanosecond count when a key on the keyboard is pressed, stopping it when the key is released and calculating how long the key was pressed down for.

So far I have tried several different structures using the modules pynput and time. I release the code below is wrong, but I'm adding it anyway, so somebody could potentially pinpoint me in the right direction.

When I run the code below it does print a time in nanoseconds. However, the time printed keeps increasing for every key I try, no matter for how long I press the key down. It seems the method: time.perf_counter_ns() does not stop counting even when the function block is finished and called again after that.

```
import pynput, time
from pynput.keyboard import Key,Listener

timer = 0
timer2 = 0

def press(Key):
    timer = time.perf_counter_ns()

def release(Key):
    timer2 = time.perf_counter_ns()
    print(timer-timer2)

with Listener(on_press=press, on_release=release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Comment: A simple debugging step that would have helped: `print(timer)` in `release()` and you'll see it's always `0`. Also your arithmetic results in a negative number: you should reverse the operands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Source of the bug

It looks like your problem is that the line `timer = time.perf_counter_ns()` in `press` is not doing what you expect.

Variables assigned to within Python functions hide variables with the same name from the parent scope(s). This means that you're assigning to a local variable called `timer`, rather than the global variable `timer` as you expect. When you calculate `timer-timer2` in `release`, you're using the global variable `timer`, the value of which never changes from `0`.

## Solution

Wrap the timers in a class that contains `timer` as a member.

```py
class Timer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.timer = None

    def press(self, key):
        self.timer = time.perf_counter_ns()

    def release(self, key):
        timer2 = time.perf_counter_ns()
        print(timer2 - self.timer)

timer = Timer()
with Listener(on_press=timer.press, on_release=timer.release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Another way is to just use the global version of `timer` in your code. This is considered bad practice, but here is how you'd do it.

```py
def press(Key):
    global timer
    timer = time.perf_counter_ns()
```

Comment: @joecode In addition to marking it as accepted, you can up-vote it as well. Votes are unlimited and free to give away, use them liberally :)

Comment: Yeah I actually did that, but as I'm new to stackoverflow, a message appeared saying votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are not publicly displayed.. 2 more to go and you'll see it